# tagx files: c:set tag, access to a property of an object

Tags: spring, spring-roo, jsp-tags

I'm using Spring Roo, and I have changed the list.tagx file to add a title at the top. This title is the value of a property of the first item. The problem is that I want to specify this property in a generic way, as an attribute of the list.tagx. Something like that:

```
<jsp:directive.attribute name="titleValue" type="java.lang.String"
        required="false" rtexprvalue="true"
        description="The value to be shown in the title" />
   ...
   <c:when test="${not empty items}">
      <c:if test="${not empty titleValue}">
         <c:set var="variable" value="${items[0].titleValue}" />
      </c:if>
   ...
```

There is a problem, because it tries to get the value of a property called 'titleValue' into the object items[0]. For instance, if I set the value of 'titleValue' as 'firstName', I want to get the value of **items[0].firstName**

Is it possible to do that?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is possible by using the `spring:eval` tag from the namespace `xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/tags"`. Try this:

```
<jsp:directive.attribute name="titleValue" type="java.lang.String"
        required="false" rtexprvalue="true"
        description="The value to be shown in the title" />
   ...
   <c:when test="${not empty items}">
      <c:if test="${not empty titleValue}">
         <c:set var="variable">
             <spring:eval expression="items[0].${titleValue}" />
         </c:set>
      </c:if>
   ...
```

EDIT: fixed typo, sorry. It wasn't `${items[0]}.${..}` but `items[0].${..}`